# Различное отображение страницы в браузере и на устройстве при одинаковом разрешении

Tags: html5, css3, responsive

Добрый день. Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему при одном и том же разрешении в браузере на ПК и на устройстве страница отображается по разному? И из-за этого я не могу нормально адаптировать.

Вот скриншоты:

[Отображение в браузере (320х568)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dm4gU.jpg)

[image: Отображение на iphone 5s (320х568)]

Ссылка на саму страницу [clouds.st](http://clouds.st)

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант, если это Safari, синхронизируй его с десктопным Safari и по инспектору кода можно увидеть, что конкретно видет этот моб браузер.